# abort() not changing headers

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-5

So this is an abort call that is within a DB::transaction() block:

```
 abort(422, 'insufficient_credits', ['statusText' => 'insufficient_credits']);
```

Unfortunately, it does not modify the actual headers of the response. Instead, it seems to be creating headers within some nested scope... not really sure how to access it:

[image: Response Image]

My JavaScript file where the call is made:

```
this.$http.post('/api/test', data).then(function(response) {
//Stuff here                
},  function(response)  {
if(response.status === 422)  {
//This triggers the output in the screenshot above
console.log(response); 
}});
```

How can I modify my code/abort error so that it actually modifies the header value? If that's not possible, is there any way of passing back and retrieving additional information alongside the response status?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `abort()`, go for a custom Response by using Symfonys `Response` class (or the corresponding Laravel helper as I did in the example):

```
return response($yourContent, $statusCode)
            ->header('Content-Type', $type)
            ->header('X-Header-One', 'Header Value')
            ->header('X-Header-Two', 'Header Value');
```